# Find the solution to $\int_0^1 |2x-3y|dy$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Find the solution to  $F(X) = \int_0^1 |2x-3y|dy$

What is correct, that we see where the function $2x-3y$ is negative or positive and we adjust the signs based on that, or:

That we already calculate to $F (X )=|2x-\frac{3}{2}|$ and we do it from here, so here we would get two cases, one for $x < 3$ and the other one for $x\geq 3$.

Can we also do it with the second approach or is it not correct? Why is that so ?

Comment: Are $X$ and $x$ the same thing? What what has $\left|2x-\frac32\right|$ to do with this problem?

Comment: Where did you get that integral? Maybe calculating the volume? I think that would give a better context to your question to know how to attack it effectively.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I calculated the integral and then got this function

Comment: *How* did you get that function? After all, an antiderivative of $2x-3y$ with respect to $y$ is $2xy-\frac32y^2$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I already inserted $0$ and $1$ into the function.

Comment: I see. So, for you, the absolute value in $|2x-3y|$ should have no influence in the answer.

Comment: Error: $2x-3$ is breakpoint.  For $0\lt x\lt 3/2$, integral has to be done in two pieces.

Answer (score 1):

In general

$$ \int\vert u\vert\,du=\frac{1}{2}u\vert u\vert+c $$

which is easily verified from $\dfrac{d}{du}\vert u\vert=\dfrac{\vert u\vert}{u}=\dfrac{u}{\vert u\vert}$.

So

$$ \int\vert u\vert\,dy=\int\vert u\vert \frac{dy}{du}\,du $$

Let $u=2x-3y$, with $x$ constant. Then $\dfrac{dy}{du}=-\dfrac{1}{3}$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^1\vert 2x-3y\vert\,dy&=&-\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1\vert 2x-3y\vert\,du\\
&=&-\frac{1}{6}\left[(2x-3y)\vert2x-3y\vert\right]_0^1\\
&=&\frac{2}{3}x\vert x\vert-\frac{1}{6}(2x-3)\vert2x-3\vert
\end{eqnarray}

This can be simplified for the three cases

1. $x<0$
2. $0\le x<\frac{3}{2}$
3. $x\ge\frac{3}{2}$

Here is a graph of the function:

[image: Graph of solution]